# Angular html component not rendering the local json data on loading the page

Tags: json, angular, constructor, html-rendering, ngoninit

```
import { Store,STORES } from '../models/store';

export class StoreLocatorComponent implements OnInit { 
public Stores: any = [];
constructor() {  
   }

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.Stores = STORES ; 
      this.Stores.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
      });
  }

}
```

HTML Part

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let store of Stores">
        {{store.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

But this html page is not rendering the values inside Stores, whereas in logs i can see that the data in STORES object has been assigned to Stores,
and ALSO the Stores data in html starts showing up when some activity is done on html page like click any random dummy button or something like that. This is probably related to how and when html page is rendered w.r.t the ngOnInit(), but can some one clarify how can i render the data of STORES on Initial Load of page WITHOUT having to click anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a symptom of the web page rendering before the binding. You can control the rendering.

Put in a variable named show and set it to false.

After this.stores has the data set show to true.

On the ul tag in HTML add this.

```
*ngIf='show'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in **ngAfterViewInit** as below.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.Stores = STORES ; 
      this.Stores.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
      });
  }
```

Comment: It does NOT work, on initial LOAD No values are displayed in the list, for rendering the data on the page i still have to click something on page.